# How can I use a variable's value as a Perl variable name?

Tags: perl, variables, symbolic-references

Sorry about all these silly questions, I've been thrust into Perl programming and I'm finding it really hard to think like a Perl programmer.

Silly question for today:
I load a pipe delimited file into a hash using the id field as the key, like so

```
#open file

my %hash;
while (<MY_FILE>) {
    chomp;

    my ($id, $path, $date) = split /\|/;

    $hash{$id} = {
        "path" => $path,
        "date" => $date
    };
}
```

There a few times, however, when I actually need the key to be the path because, for whatever reason (and no, it can't be changed) the id isn't unique, so I had the bright idea that I could put it all into a subroutine and pass the name of the variable to use as the key to it, kinda like so:

```
load_hash("path");

sub load_hash {
    my $key = shift;

    #do stuff, and then in while loop
    $hash{${$key}} = #and so on
}
```

but in perldb x ${$key} is always undef, although x ${path} prints the value in $path.

Is there some way of doing what I'm trying to?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
use Carp 'confess';

sub load_hash {
    my $key = shift;

    # ...

    while (...) {
        # ...
        my %line;  # important that this is *inside* the loop
        @line{qw (id path date)} = split /\|/;
        confess "BUG: unknown key '$key'"  unless exists $line{$key};  # error checking
        $hash{$line{$key}} = \%line;
        delete $line{$key};  # assuming you don't want the key value duplicated
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You're trying to use "symbolic references".  If you have a problem and you think "hey, I'll solve this with symbolic references" you now have two problems.

First off, they only work on globals.  You've declared `$path` as a lexical (only visible in the block which it was declared) and thus load_path can't see it.  No, don't make `$path` global.

Second, symbolic refs create spaghetti code.  Globals are bad enough.  They can be accessed anywhere, anytime by anything.  With a symbolic reference to a global you can't even see WHICH global is being accessed.  This makes it impossible to track what might change what.  This is why `strict` turns them off.  Turn on `strict` and leave it on until you know when you should turn it off.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it seems this is fine.

```
my %hash;
while (<MY_FILE>) {
    chomp;

    my ($id, $path, $date) = split /\|/;

    $hash{$path} = {
        "path" => $path,
        "date" => $date
    };
}
```

But I'd probably move the parsing of the line into a function and leave the hash assignment to the main loop.  Parsing the line is a clear chunk of logic and can be totally separated from assigning the line to the file hash.  A good sign is that `%hash` does not have to be global.

```
my %hash;
while (<MY_FILE>) {
    my $line = parse_line($_);

    my $id = $line->{path};
    $hash{$id} = $line;
}


my @fields = qw(id path date);
sub parse_line {
    my $line = shift;
    chomp $line;

    my %data;
    # This is assigning to a hash slice.  Look it up, its handy.
    @data{@fields} = split m{\|}, $line;

    return \%data;
}
```

Comment: Don't worry, I always use strict and warnings (although I had to turn off warnings when trying this).

Comment: @Sparkles, if you had to turn off warnings, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: upvoted for quoting the most self-righteous Perl hater alive?  (Naggum is the most self-righteous Perl hater, but he died.)

Comment: @Sparkles That's some new definition of "always". Don't just turn warnings off, figure out what's causing the warning and fix it.  @jrockway I thought I was quoting mjd (he was talking about AUTOLOAD).  Seems jwz wasn't the original, either: http://➡.ws/醺緎